# Assign a variable by returning a value from a block when assignment is nil

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to set a variable to a value but the value might be `nil`. I need to do some processing if it is. Here's some example code:

```
car = cached_car || do
  new_car = Car.new 
  # do stuff to the object here
  send_car_to_cache(new_car)
  new_car
end
```

Unfortunately it's telling me that there is an unexpected `do` block. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: the context may have been confusing, so here is the real world scenario where I am using it.

```
def tableView(table_view, cellForRowAtIndexPath:index_path)
  cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CELL_ID) || begin
    PostTableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(
      UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: CELL_ID
    )
  end

  configure_cell(cell, index_path)
  cell
end
```

Comment: Your question is "What am I doing wrong here?", not "How can I fix this?" Has your question been answered? Yes!

Comment: That wasn't my point. Which answer(s) actually answer your question?

Comment: I answered my own question. I was using the wrong keyword. `do` instead of `begin`. I should maybe edit my question so that it is more helpful as I have a better idea of what I'm doing now.

Comment: No need to edit. My point is that @sawa was the only one to answer your question, "What am I doing wrong here?", by explaining *why* your code construct does not work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are correct, that is the only answer that actually explains why this wasn't working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welp, I figured it out. I didn't want to use `do`, the right keyword is `begin`.

```
car = cached_car || begin
  new_car = Car.new 
  # do stuff to the object here
  send_car_to_cache(new_car)
  new_car
end
```

Now if `cached_car` is null I can construct an object and return it.

Comment: You could also just use parentheses: `old_car = nil; new_car = old_car || (new_car = Car.new; ...; new_car)` (spread out over several lines).

Comment: This is a solution to your problem, but not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
car = cached_car
unless car
  car = Car.new
  # do stuff to the object here
  send_car_to_cache(car)
end
```

It might make sense to extract that into a method:

```
def new_car
  Car.new.tap do |new_car|
    # do stuff to the object here
    send_car_to_cache(new_car)
  end
end
```

What could be used like this:

```
car = cached_car || new_car
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wanted to avoid constructing a method for it. I've updated my question with a real example.

Answer (score 3):

On the right side of `||` has to be an object. `do` starts a block, which is not an object.